# Assembler: Cant figure out where to go from here

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So i am currently working on an assignment for class. I dont need the work done for me though that is always helpful if there is an explanation with it. I really just want a push in the right direction. My assignment is:

*Write an assembly language program that solves the following problem.  The Albatross Company has four salespeople (1 to 4) who sell five different products (1 to 5).  Once a day, each salesperson reports their sales of each product.  These reports are consolidated over time into a file.  Each record in the file contains three values:
•         The salesperson number from 1 to 4 (3 characters wide, right justified)
•         The product number from 1 to 5 (3 characters wide, right justified)
•         The dollar value of that product sold that day by that salesperson (9 characters wide, right justified)
Your program must prompt the user for a file name, process the file, and report the totals for each salesperson and for each product.  A sample data file called “Albatross.dat” is provided to allow you to test your program.
Your program must be able to handle a data file that contains any number of sales records.  This means that it is possible for the input data file to contain multiple records for each salesperson and product combination.  Do not write your program so that it always (and only) expects the number of records that happen to be in the sample data file.  Your program will be tested and graded by executing it with a data file that contains fewer records than the sample data file, the sample data file, and finally with a data file that contains more records than the sample data file.*

So far this is what I have:

```
.data

askfile BYTE "Enter the data file name: ",0
fileMessage BYTE "Error while opening file: ",0dh,0ah,0
fileName BYTE 256 DUP(0)
byteCount DWORD ?
handle DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

mov edx,OFFSET askfile
call WriteString

;File name

mov edx,OFFSET filename
mov ecx,SIZEOF filename
call ReadString
mov byteCount,eax

;Open

mov edx,OFFSET filename
call OpenInputFile
cmp eax,INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
je file_error
mov handle,eax
jmp Alpha

file_error:
mov edx,OFFSET fileMessage
call WriteString
jmp Omega

Alpha:
.data
BUFFER_SIZE = 17
buffer BYTE BUFFER_SIZE DUP(?)
bytesRead DWORD ?

.code

;Read from file

mov eax,handle
mov edx,OFFSET buffer
mov ecx,BUFFER_SIZE
call ReadFromFile
jc read_error
cmp eax,BUFFER_SIZE
jl Omega

read_error:
mov edx,OFFSET readMessage
call WriteString
jmp Omega


main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You've got as far as an open file, so read the file line by line, add up the numbers, stop when you reach the end, and print out the results.

Comment: "Just add up the numbers" may be an issue. For each "dollar value" you find, you'll want to add it to at least two sums - total for this salesperson, and total for this product. You might want a sum for "this salesperson, this product" too... although the "specification" doesn't seem to demand it. I envision a "matrix of sums". Why 17 bytes for a buffer size? Are these values comma-delimited? If so, wouldn't you want 18 bytes? If not, 15? Well, you've got "Albatross.dat" to go by. Lord, I hope "dollar value" is an integer, not "349.99"...

Comment: buffer size is 17 because it is 3 characters wide for sales person, 3 for product, 9 for product number, cr, lf. luckily it is whole dollar amounts. the values are seperated by blank spaces. how would i get the sums though. i know i need to do a two dimensional array but i do not quite understand two dimensional arrays. in a two dimensional array if salesperson 1 sells item 1 for 1000 will (1,1) always be 1000? and how would i even sort it so its in order of sales person or product?

Comment: how do I take info from the file and populate an array with 4 rows 5 columns. 1 row for each sales person and 1 row for each product. the 3rd element on each line in the file is the sales amount I was thinking that those numbers would populate each of the elements in the array and i call them by calling the row and column number and adding them together then "printing" them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin with writing and testing a2i2a procedures. When you have this and file I/O the rest is straightforward.

Comment: what are a2i2a procedures?

Comment: ASCII to integer and integer to ASCII. If I correctly understood, you will need to convert string to integers and back.